# I need help selecting a jQuery Zoom Image Map

Tags: jquery, plugins, maps, zooming

I need help selecting a Jquery plugin that respect this requirements, it is a city map:

1. **Design**: Don't want to use Google Maps or similar, I want to use a custom Background Image
2. **Regions**: I need to design regions of the city like: downtown, etc.
3. **Zoom**: The possibility of zooming in on this areas with scroll or click
4. **Markers**: I need to put markers in this map with toll-tip

I Know that Google Maps does this with custom programming, I want to know if there is another solution out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using **`SVG`**, but the areas design can be of the issue, but as the result you can *pan* / *zoom* / *scroll* your map and do whatever you want with it without any *API* \ *Plugins*.

Comment: I like that idea, I wanted to know if there is already something made.

Comment: @Unykvis, probably, but I don't think that there is smth. ready for you particular region. I'm sure that you can find world map in SVG, but I'm not sure about the rest of the world, especially suburbs etc.